# iphone-like widget library for Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Are there any OSS libraries/collections that provide some of the look and feel of iPhone apps (i.e. bg colors, button, drop down list shape/colors, etc) for Android.

I've seen a few apps like that on the Google Market.

BTW I'm not talking about skinning the Android Home screen to make it look like iPhone.

Comment: Why?  If people want apps that look like iOS apps, they buy an iPhone.  Google has a great set of guidelines for making apps the Android way.

Comment: Here you have one library which you could use: https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/android-uitableview

Comment: the client dictates this requirement :)

Comment: Also, are you going to make it look like < iOS 6 or iOS 7?

Comment: Show your client reviews of these apps that look like iOS apps. :) Sometimes you have to just do what the client says, but I highly recommend fighting it if possible -- Android users *hate* seeing things that look like iOS; it's usually a dead giveaway that the app is terrible.

Comment: @dmon: ios5/6 is fine, we're not trying to copy iOS verbatim

Comment: @koppock android still has a long way to catch up to iOS in terms of polished look and feel. for non-technical end-users, that's really all that matters - a pretty and shiny app! :)

Answer (score 0):

The way to i did that is with Images, and adjust it. But i prefer a original UI, not a copy from iOS.